# mysql ADDTIME not working

Tags: mysql

I am try to add time by following code

```
SELECT ADDTIME('13:20:32.50','1:39:27.50', '13:20:32.50') as TotalTime;
```

But it shows error: **#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ADDTIME'**. What should I do? Is my code wrong?

Comment: You can have only 2 parameters, try ADDTIME(ADDTIME('13:20:32.50','1:39:27.50'),'13:20:32.50')

Comment: Check the syntax before using a function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ADDTIME()` function

```
SET @t1 = '12:00:00', @t2 = '15:30:00',@t3 = '15:30:00';
Set @t4= ADDTIME(@t1,@t2);    
SELECT ADDTIME(@t4,@t3);
```

Answer (score 1):

In you can use only two parameter in ADDTIME

ADDTIME() adds expr2 to expr1 and returns the result.

```
SELECT ADDTIME(expr1, expr2) as required_datetime;
```